# ArrayCollection of One Element as DataProvider

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I use httpservice with object result to load data on dropdownlist.
Some time the result is only one element. In this case, an error appear. I know that another solution is to e4x result format but I think that in this case it's longer.
So if someone could help me?

Thanks

Comment: This message appear : Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "P- John SMITH" to mx.collections.ArrayCollection. P- John SMITH is the content of my only one result. thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to covert a string to an array based on the error.  Can you show us the code that creates the error?  Are you sure that your remote service is sending back an array if there is only a single result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **either change the service** to always return a collection **or** you will have to do a **preemptive casting in Flex**.

In Flex,

- cast the result as :*
- use result.**hasOwnProperty**("source") or similar.
- if true, you have an array collection, cast as array collection and resume
- if false, you have a string or just the one item. Cast it and resume.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
if( event.result.ParamRGT.tireurs.tireur is ArrayCollection )
{ 
arListeTireur = event.result.ParamRGT.tireurs.tireur; 
} 
else{ arListeTireur = new ArrayCollection( [event.result.ParamRGT.tireurs.tireur] ); 
}
```

instead of `arListeTireur = event.result.ParamRGT.tireurs.tireur`